# Request.User with custom auth backend

Tags: django, authentication

i implemented custom simple auth backend (two methods - authenticate and get_user, nothing special), now i could successfully authenticate and login my `customUser`, but what should i need to do to have possibility call `request.user` with my `customUser` in the views methods? For now it just give me an error `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`

**UPD.** Turns out, i forgot to add default `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` in `settings.py`. It worked now

Comment: Make sure that both methods return the the user object -- maybe you have a condition/branch that misses doing so?

Comment: You can post that as an answer, then accept it! :)